# I have a list of styled words, how I can transform in plain text?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of styled words after I used apply:

```
Style[#1, #2] & @@@ {{"a", Bold}, {"b", Red}, {"c", Blue}, {"d", Purple}}
```

How I can transform this list in a text of separated words?

Comment: Map `ToString` onto the list. It will discard any number of nested `Style`s, and leave the string only.

Comment: `Row@Riffle[list, " "]` will preserve the styles.

Comment: Ah, this is exactly what I was searching for! Thank you @Bob

Answer (score 2):

You can apply `Part` to any head:

```
lst = Style[#1, #2] & @@@ {{"a", Bold}, {"b", Red}, {"c", Blue}, {"d",Purple}}
Part[#, 1] & /@ lst
```

I'm not sure what "a text of separated words" is, but maybe it is this:

```
StringRiffle[Part[#, 1] & /@ lst, " "]
```

Or, if you actually mean to keep the formatting, you can just use `Row` on your list.

```
Row[lst, " "]
```